# how to replay varnish ban

Tags: magento2, varnish

my CMS (Magento 2) send some BAN requests to varnish when doing some CMS objects updates.
Is there a way to capture the URLs that were banned from varnish so I can re-query (warm) before a customer hit those URLs (MISS)?

it would be ideal. I might update my CMS code to detect when the BAN is sent, read the tags and try to detect which URLs are impacted. First it could not be that easy, second it could be a lot of URLs, maybe some of them are not that popular and were not already cached.
so ideally to speed up warming, I would only focuses on those BAN url that were already cached.
only varnish (reliably) knows. how to capture this?
I tried the ban.list command, but only get tags.
I heard about varnishreplay but it has been retired and not sure about what it did exactly.

is there a way to query cached URLs from varnish based on tags so I get those URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `varnishlog` to capture the URL and tags the moment they get stored in cache.

The following logging command can be used:

```
varnishlog -g request -b -i berequrl -I berespheader:X-Magento-Tags
```

This will just display the logs that are stored in a circular memory buffer. This means that if you don't continuously monitor them, you might lose some data.

If you've installed Varnish via packages, there should already by a systemd service file for `varnishlog` in `/lib/systemd/system/varnishlog-errors.service`.

You can copy that file and turn it into a service that logs cached entries. Please make sure you modify the parameters of the `varnishlog` command inside the service file.

> Please also be aware that these file can grow very quickly depending on your traffic patterns and your hit rate.